# How can I solve server error 500 which I am getting during django app deployment on heroku?

Tags: python, django, heroku

When I set debug equals to false my app doesnot work on both local n live env but when I set debug equals  true it works all right in local env but gives same server 500 error on live env.
This is the github repo for my django project: [https://github.com/Pran1001/HomeFinder] and
settings.py file : https://github.com/Pran1001/HomeFinder/blob/main/HOMEFINDER/settings.py
below are the logs which I am get from running heroku logs command

2021-12-08T15:45:37.068695+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/admin/css/responsive.b128bdf0edef.css" host=searchyourghar.herokuapp.com request_id=44638661-3f75-4f03-a4fc-75e04d9ff9da fwd="94.212.43.57" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=3746 protocol=http
2021-12-08T15:45:37.070941+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.56.115 - - [08/Dec/2021:15:45:37 +0000] "GET /static/admin/js/nav_sidebar.7605597ddf52.js HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "http://searchyourghar.herokuapp.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:94.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/94.0"
2021-12-08T15:45:37.070987+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.86.24 - - [08/Dec/2021:15:45:37 +0000] "GET /static/admin/css/login.c35adf41bb6e.css HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "http://searchyourghar.herokuapp.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:94.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/94.0"
2021-12-08T15:45:37.073639+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/admin/css/login.c35adf41bb6e.css" host=searchyourghar.herokuapp.com request_id=827c0aba-cb65-4ed1-a79e-7898eeb989bd fwd="94.212.43.57" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=765 protocol=http
2021-12-08T15:45:37.073837+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/admin/css/fonts.168bab448fee.css" host=searchyourghar.herokuapp.com request_id=4c954790-4952-40ef-aa71-da865affdbc0 fwd="94.212.43.57" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=544 protocol=http
2021-12-08T15:45:37.074174+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.53.153 - - [08/Dec/2021:15:45:37 +0000] "GET /static/admin/css/fonts.168bab448fee.css HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "http://searchyourghar.herokuapp.com/static/admin/css/base.1f418065fc2c.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:94.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/94.0"
2021-12-08T15:45:37.194120+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Light-webfont.c73eb1ceba33.woff" host=searchyourghar.herokuapp.com request_id=a230408c-d36b-470b-b161-c4da33e46b72 fwd="94.212.43.57" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=86000 protocol=http
2021-12-08T15:45:37.194491+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.59.109 - - [08/Dec/2021:15:45:37 +0000] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Regular-webfont.35b07eb2f871.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "http://searchyourghar.herokuapp.com/static/admin/css/fonts.168bab448fee.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:94.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/94.0"
2021-12-08T15:45:37.195129+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Regular-webfont.35b07eb2f871.woff" host=searchyourghar.herokuapp.com request_id=395d781b-e818-42c8-a58d-2c72e616b8ea fwd="94.212.43.57" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=86184 protocol=http
2021-12-08T15:45:37.196221+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.56.115 - - [08/Dec/2021:15:45:37 +0000] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Light-webfont.c73eb1ceba33.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "http://searchyourghar.herokuapp.com/static/admin/css/fonts.168bab448fee.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:94.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/94.0"
2021-12-08T16:04:38.994010+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.19.184 - - [08/Dec/2021:16:04:38 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 145 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.93 Safari/537.36"
2021-12-08T16:04:38.994689+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=searchyourghar.herokuapp.com request_id=e92cb7ec-647e-4adb-a44e-7fe9829ff4ae fwd="49.32.177.39" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=23ms status=500 bytes=409 protocol=https
2021-12-08T16:36:55.142048+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2021-12-08T16:36:55.155274+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2021-12-08T16:36:57.179539+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2021-12-08T16:36:57.258159+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-08 16:36:57 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2021-12-08T16:36:57.258165+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-08 16:36:57 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2021-12-08T16:36:57.276346+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-08 16:36:57 +0000] [4] [INFO] Handling signal: term
2021-12-08T16:36:57.280233+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-08 16:36:57 +0000] [4] [WARNING] Worker with pid 10 was terminated due to signal 15
2021-12-08T16:36:57.282512+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-08 16:36:57 +0000] [4] [WARNING] Worker with pid 9 was terminated due to signal 15
2021-12-08T16:36:57.376945+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-08 16:36:57 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2021-12-08T16:36:57.534660+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2021-12-08T17:04:50.392009+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2021-12-08T17:04:50.428224+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2021-12-08T17:05:11.622919+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn HOMEFINDER.wsgi --log-file -`
2021-12-08T17:05:12.961144+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-08 17:05:12 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
2021-12-08T17:05:12.961672+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-08 17:05:12 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:51959 (4)
2021-12-08T17:05:12.968098+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-08 17:05:12 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2021-12-08T17:05:12.968106+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-08 17:05:12 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2021-12-08T17:05:12.982999+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-08 17:05:12 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2021-12-08T17:05:12.983061+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-12-08T17:05:14.577236+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.14.193 - - [08/Dec/2021:17:05:14 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 145 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36"
2021-12-08T17:05:14.577460+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=searchyourghar.herokuapp.com request_id=8a32ba7c-2a96-4c84-b992-7d611c840219 fwd="115.69.255.136" dyno=web.1 connect=7ms service=73ms status=500 bytes=409 protocol=https
2021-12-08T17:05:14.898838+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.14.193 - - [08/Dec/2021:17:05:14 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "https://searchyourghar.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36"
2021-12-08T17:05:14.899034+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=searchyourghar.herokuapp.com request_id=027aa7ed-58d1-4707-ad57-4d173d11e4f8 fwd="115.69.255.136" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=417 protocol=https
2021-12-08T17:32:07.675458+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `python manage.py migrate` by user pvsharadkdare@gmail.com
2021-12-08T17:32:33.856090+00:00 heroku[run.1130]: Awaiting client
2021-12-08T17:32:33.890691+00:00 heroku[run.1130]: Starting process with command `python manage.py migrate`
2021-12-08T17:32:33.907839+00:00 heroku[run.1130]: State changed from starting to up
2021-12-08T17:32:53.094905+00:00 heroku[run.1130]: Process exited with status 0
2021-12-08T17:32:53.565077+00:00 heroku[run.1130]: State changed from up to complete
2021-12-08T17:33:48.781677+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.87.26 - - [08/Dec/2021:17:33:48 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 145 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.93 Safari/537.36"
2021-12-08T17:33:48.782080+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=searchyourghar.herokuapp.com request_id=6c59a4f9-ab72-4014-9060-23baa93dd3eb fwd="49.32.177.39" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=21ms status=500 bytes=409 protocol=https
2021-12-08T17:33:49.443549+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.87.26 - - [08/Dec/2021:17:33:49 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "https://searchyourghar.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.93 Safari/537.36"
2021-12-08T17:33:49.444000+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=searchyourghar.herokuapp.com request_id=43276420-28fe-429f-8407-5a627cc8658c fwd="49.32.177.39" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=417 protocol=https
2021-12-08T18:08:07.556732+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2021-12-08T18:08:07.562473+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2021-12-08T18:08:08.285527+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2021-12-08T18:08:08.331126+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-08 18:08:08 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2021-12-08T18:08:08.331259+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-08 18:08:08 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2021-12-08T18:08:08.331334+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-08 18:08:08 +0000] [4] [INFO] Handling signal: term
2021-12-08T18:08:08.334633+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-08 18:08:08 +0000] [4] [WARNING] Worker with pid 10 was terminated due to signal 15
2021-12-08T18:08:08.431827+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-08 18:08:08 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2021-12-08T18:08:08.561654+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2021-12-10T16:10:06.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user pvsharadkdare@gmail.com
2021-12-10T16:11:09.817203+00:00 app[api]: Release v17 created by user pvsharadkdare@gmail.com
2021-12-10T16:11:09.817203+00:00 app[api]: Deploy b9bbbdc0 by user pvsharadkdare@gmail.com
2021-12-10T16:11:16.142609+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2021-12-10T16:11:20.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-12-10T16:11:38.011141+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn HOMEFINDER.wsgi --log-file -`
2021-12-10T16:11:39.144498+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-10 16:11:39 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
2021-12-10T16:11:39.145004+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-10 16:11:39 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:58807 (4)
2021-12-10T16:11:39.145041+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-10 16:11:39 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2021-12-10T16:11:39.147986+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-10 16:11:39 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2021-12-10T16:11:39.218222+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-10 16:11:39 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2021-12-10T16:11:39.712287+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-12-10T16:11:59.489652+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `python manage.py migrate` by user pvsharadkdare@gmail.com
2021-12-10T16:12:15.651729+00:00 heroku[run.7161]: Awaiting client
2021-12-10T16:12:15.671700+00:00 heroku[run.7161]: Starting process with command `python manage.py migrate`
2021-12-10T16:12:15.862907+00:00 heroku[run.7161]: State changed from starting to up
2021-12-10T16:12:35.634198+00:00 heroku[run.7161]: Process exited with status 0
2021-12-10T16:12:35.707367+00:00 heroku[run.7161]: State changed from up to complete
2021-12-10T16:13:04.741644+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=searchyourghar.herokuapp.com request_id=3649a6e8-eb78-4977-9520-b0a956d4fa22 fwd="49.32.165.103" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=75ms status=500 bytes=409 protocol=https
2021-12-10T16:13:04.742026+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.63.23 - - [10/Dec/2021:16:13:04 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 145 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.93 Safari/537.36"
2021-12-10T16:13:05.329170+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=searchyourghar.herokuapp.com request_id=52f47990-078a-470f-a277-46a7e28d8aa8 fwd="49.32.165.103" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=23ms status=404 bytes=417 protocol=https
2021-12-10T16:13:05.330054+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.63.23 - - [10/Dec/2021:16:13:05 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "https://searchyourghar.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.93 Safari/537.36"
2021-12-10T16:14:24.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user pvsharadkdare@gmail.com
2021-12-10T16:14:55.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build output: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/8ec0dbe7-ca08-421c-ac6e-e0ab5aa5cba7/activity/builds/edbbb997-a64d-4a8e-8742-34c48e35b73e
2021-12-10T16:18:52.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user pvsharadkdare@gmail.com
2021-12-10T16:19:44.049664+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 65f756fe by user pvsharadkdare@gmail.com
2021-12-10T16:19:44.049664+00:00 app[api]: Release v18 created by user pvsharadkdare@gmail.com
2021-12-10T16:19:44.320948+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2021-12-10T16:19:44.360325+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2021-12-10T16:19:45.180360+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2021-12-10T16:19:45.225811+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-10 16:19:45 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2021-12-10T16:19:45.225842+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-10 16:19:45 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2021-12-10T16:19:45.226007+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-10 16:19:45 +0000] [4] [INFO] Handling signal: term
2021-12-10T16:19:45.229154+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-10 16:19:45 +0000] [4] [WARNING] Worker with pid 9 was terminated due to signal 15
2021-12-10T16:19:45.330054+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-10 16:19:45 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2021-12-10T16:19:45.492768+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2021-12-10T16:19:54.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-12-10T16:20:02.206645+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn HOMEFINDER.wsgi --log-file -`
2021-12-10T16:20:04.189983+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-10 16:20:04 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
2021-12-10T16:20:04.190583+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-10 16:20:04 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:46059 (4)
2021-12-10T16:20:04.190655+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-10 16:20:04 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2021-12-10T16:20:04.211982+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-10 16:20:04 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2021-12-10T16:20:04.301671+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-10 16:20:04 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2021-12-10T16:20:04.640139+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-12-10T16:20:09.998831+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.5.37 - - [10/Dec/2021:16:20:09 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 145 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.93 Safari/537.36"
2021-12-10T16:20:09.999580+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=searchyourghar.herokuapp.com request_id=e765dc12-a577-4d34-9508-4370b49d3010 fwd="49.32.165.103" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=89ms status=500 bytes=409 protocol=https

Pls ask me for any more information needed!

Comment: There should be other log lines above this that provide context for the error. Please [edit] your question and add that context.

Comment: You should put your app name at the bottom  in ``INSTALLED_APPS`` list

Comment: @AnkitTiwari after I do this I get an error as - failed to push some refs

Comment: Hello @Smiling ***failed to push some refs*** - this error is related to your git check your current branch

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).